# Register Cloned VMs on Rancher

Tags: rancher

When I try to register a new VM on my Rancher Console, an existing one is removed to put this new one in place. Both Vms are ubuntu srv, with different IP address and different Mc Address for their network card.

Can this be due to the fact that those 2 VMs have been cloned ?
How (based on what) is rancher generating an identifier for each host ?

Thanks

Comment: Do both the VMs have the same IP address? How do they register with rancher server? When the VMs were cloned, was the old VM already registered with Rancher? You might have to clean up `/var/lib/rancher` directory before cloning.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, yes both VMs have different IP addresses. I don't remember if the cloned VM was registered during the clone command. To register the VM I used the add host command, insert the ip address than copy paste the command generated by Rancher. Next time I will try to clean the /var/lib/rancher folder.

Comment: I actually identified the 2 concerned VMs, Let's say VM1 (with 2 container deployed ) and VM2 (with no container deployed) .When I reboot VM2 it take the place of VM1 on the console. If I reboot VM1 it take the place of VM2 on the console BUT all containers are gone !! and impossible to found them anywhere !!

Comment: Can you check the IP address of the VMs? If there is some kind of NAT? If both VMs are identified by the same IP address, there is a possibility to experience the behavior you are describing.

Comment: No NAT for sure, just 2 VMs with 2 different IP addresses. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after testing on my side it appear that clean up /var/lib/rancher, as mentionned in the comment by "leodotcloud" fix the issue for me. But I am still interested to know how rancher is identifying VMs.